# Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Transport closed")

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm using Google custom metric to write custom metrics to the cloud. My code looks like this:

```
var client = MetricServiceClient.Create();
// ... 
client.CreateTimeSeries(name, timeSeries);
```

When I running it on my machine, it's working great.

When I running it on production, it works great until stopped. I'm getting this error message:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Transport closed")
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Cloud.Monitoring.V3.MetricService.MetricServiceClient.CreateTimeSeries(CreateTimeSeriesRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.Monitoring.V3.MetricServiceClientImpl.CreateTimeSeries(CreateTimeSeriesRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at XXX in XXX.cs:line 90
```

or this similar error:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Socket closed")
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Cloud.Monitoring.V3.MetricService.MetricServiceClient.CreateTimeSeries(CreateTimeSeriesRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Cloud.Monitoring.V3.MetricServiceClientImpl.CreateTimeSeries(CreateTimeSeriesRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
```

This error repeating from time to time. It looks like 99% of the time it's working.

What the problem here? How to solve it?

Comment: Those errors seem to have to do with the transport layer, rather than something in your code.  You could consider using OpenCensus, rather than the Monitoring, libraries to do metric instrumentation.

Comment: Could you add additional tracing to your call, to obtain more details of this error? 

e.g. GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=tcp,connectivity_state,http,http2_stream_state

(https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md)

Comment: I have the same issue..did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not really solved it. But hide it by doing multiple retries...